# N Hibernate Session.Delete Foreign key

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, c#-4.0, nhibernate, sql-delete

i have a model called Wftask in my model i have foreign keys and this is the map

```
 Table("WfTask");
        Id(m => m.Id).Column("Id");
        Map(m => m.WfInstanceId);
        Map(m => m.OwnerGroupId);
        Map(m => m.Status);
        Map(m => m.DocId);
        Map(m => m.StepNo);
        Map(m => m.Comment).Length(500);
        Map(m => m.ActionDate);
        References(x => x.Action).Column("WfActionId").Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.WfState).Column("WfStateId").Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.WfTaskDetail).Column("WfTaskDetailId").Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Owner).Column("OwnerId").ForeignKey("FK_Person_WfTask_OwnerId").Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Actor).Column("ActorId").ForeignKey("FK_Person_WfTask_ActorId").Cascade.All();
        Map(m => m.ViewState);
        Map(m => m.Deleted);
        Map(m => m.Flag);
        References(x => x.WfVersionId).Column("WfVersionId").Cascade.All();
      //  HasManyToMany(x => x.PosibleActions).Table("WfPosibleActions").ChildKeyColumn("WfActionId").ParentKeyColumn("WftaskId");
        HasManyToMany(x => x.PosibleActions).Cascade.All().Table("WfPosibleActions").ChildKeyColumn("WfActionId").ParentKeyColumn("WftaskId");
    }
```

the problem is when i wanted to delete wftask object the Nhibernate Delete WfActionId Which is the primery key in table WfActions and other foreign keys the same how can i change my map to delelete only wftask and wfposibleactiontable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using cascade on `many-to-one` relation, mapped as

```
References(x => x.Action)
  .Column("WfActionId")
  .Cascade.All(); // that means, issue delete on current deletion
```

But that type of reference *(unless in `one-to-one` in fact)* should not be `.Cascade.All()`. There really could be other items *(sibling wftasks)* referencing the same row/identifier

To solve your issue, use this cascade:

```
.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

which should do what you expect *(during the `Add` and `Update`)* - except the deletion. That should be done separtely, explicitly... not by mapping